# ML model or not - For small feature set

Tags: regression, machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, neural-networks, classification

I have a dataset with 1500 rows and 5-8 features.

Can ML model be applied in cases when there is only 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 features?

How can I decide whether it is okay to use ML model or tell the business users that it is not possible to build a ML model with just 5 features? Instead we should rely on some simple rule-based model or so

Can help me with this? or direct me to resources where I can learn more about this

Answer (score 2):

It's more than possible to build an ML model with 5-8 features. It all comes down to the business problem you're trying to solve, what you're trying to predict, and how much predictive power those 5-8 features hold. The only way to really know is to try - test out a few models and see how they perform.